# Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes it convert "∞" to "?"

Tags: c#

I want infinity Symbol i my string. i used following Code to get infinity symbol

```
 char.ConvertFromUtf32(8734)
```

and it convert to json when json is encoded ie.

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json)
```

then it convert "∞" to "?" symbol

so how i can resolve this problem. please Help me.

thanks.

Comment: Which ASCII character would you like it to use for the infinity symbol?

Comment: ASCII char values only go up to 255 so the fact that the number is 8734 should immediately let you know it's not ASCII. The more you know~*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The infinity sign `∞` is not part of the ASCII character set. So by using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` you explicitly exclude it from the string, effectivly replacing it with a placeholder, in this case `?`

Since you use the resulting byte array for a JSON reply, you might want to consider using `UTF8` inxtead of `ASCII`

Comment: Can you give me one the Example So I can understand better. thanks

Comment: Start by simply replacing `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(...)` with `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`, then work from there. Don't forget to set  `charset="UTF-8"` for the page.

Comment: +1. @Girish, please check [MSDN Encoding.ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx) for sample and precise definition of what considered ASCII by the encoding class and when `?` is used.